# Great Motherboard with Maybe Integrated Audio Chip?

Tags: motherboard, pc, desktop, windows

I won some money so I can replace my current motherboard, Gigabyte Z370 AORUS Gaming 5 (rev. 1.0) in which the sound stinks.  I need suggestions on a replacement with the requirements below.  I'll be amazed if you could recommend a perfect replacement.

**Motherboard Requirements**

- Socket: LGA1151
- Form Factor: ATX
- RAM Size: (4 x 16 GB) Dual Channels of RAM (288-PIN DDR4 SDRAM DDR4 3000Mhz (PC4 24000)
- Audio: Integrated audio chip (not really necessary but would be nice)
- Minimum Requirements due to Pioneer Blu-ray player

  - Graphics: Intel® HD Graphics 630
  - Output: HDCP 2.2/HDMI 2.0a
  - ATAPI interface: Serial ATA Revision 3.0
  - Other: Intel® SGX(Software Guard Extensions)
  - Other: Intel® 200 series motherboard

Comment: While you can probably still find motherboards with this socket, Intel has moved on to newer generations of CPUs that use a different socket already. If you're having trouble finding a board with LGA1151, consider just getting a dedicated sound card. The board you have now is quite good for its time.

Comment: ArtofCode, you edited out a huge chunk of background that I spent a lot of time on.  Without it, I don't think anyone is going to answer this question.  I was trying to create an interesting story so they would be invested in the question and so would be more likely to answer it.  Can you please put it back?

Comment: Romen, thanks for your help.  The problem with the current board is that the audio chip doesn't work.  Gigabyte deliberately deprecated it when they created a new campaign for another product.  Giga still sold the motherboard, touting its sound abilities even though they deprecated it.  Really sleazy, no?  I sued Gigabyte and won.  That's why I have money to get a different board, hopefully something with better sound.  I can get another Gigabyte, I don't mind.  It's just that with this board, the current driver doesn't allow the software to function.  Giga also won't release the old driver.

Comment: @Romen Romen, thanks for your help. The problem with the current board is that the audio chip doesn't work. Gigabyte deliberately deprecated it when they created a new campaign for another product. Giga still sold the motherboard, touting its sound abilities even though they deprecated it. Really sleazy, no? I sued Gigabyte and won. That's why I have money to get a different board, hopefully something with better sound. I can get another Gigabyte, I don't mind. It's just that with this board, the current driver messes with the software. Giga also won't release the old driver.  They "lost" it.

Answer (score 1):

Go buy a good sound card, and plug it into a pci-e slot on your motherboard.

How about the newest sound blaster whatever AE-5 last time I checked.

Answer (score 0):

your AORUS Gaming 5 mobo spec shows

> Realtek® ALC1220 codec
>
> Support for Sound BlasterX 720°
>
> High Definition Audio   2/4/5.1/7.1-channel

*Problem is even with a high end audio codec you can have poor audio if the manufacturer doesn't properly shield or uses poor components.*

Is this true with that specific mobo you mentioned, I do not know.  When you only say *the sound stinks* that is very subjective and can be caused by a number of things.  To say *the audio chip doesn't work* yes it is possible that model motherboard you have not designed well with regards to audio.  Or if *it doesn't work* then that strongly insinuates a *broken* motherboard... and a replacement would be just fine.

Look at any enthusiast motherboard from any other maker... asrock, asus, evga, msi.  They all use Realtek.  Many of the premium top of the line motherboards all use the ALC1220 codec at the moment, the other most popular was 892.  While possible it could be a gigabyte *problem* with how they integrated audio on that specific motherboard that is purely speculation at this point with nothing else to go on.

Audio nowadays is all ruled by the realtek chip integrated on motherboards, simply check the audio specs of motherboards.  If any of those does not meet your audio quality standards, however you measure that, you are then looking at a professional type audio card that plugs in via PCI-E and will all be shielded and purpose built, and not cheap, and then would likely not support your software [games].

> It's just that with this board the current driver doesn't allow the software to function.

This does not mean the mobo or audio design is flawed.  You need to be more forthcoming with all the information.  The software that generates the audio can easily be 50% or more of the problem and would be unfair to blame it all on the audio driver / chipset / motherboard.  Then there are the speakers you are using, as well as your own hearing that could be the problem.

Comment: I was forthcoming with information but the Romen, the moderator in his wisdom took down all the background information I provided.  Here is the story I had actually written by the moderator had taken down.

Comment: I currently have a Gigabyte Z370 AORUS Gaming 5 (rev. 1.0) but I sued Gigabyte for fraud and got a little more than $1k back in court. Yay!! Why did I sue? Well, the motherboard came with an integrated audio chip that was advertised to produce SoundBlaster card quality sound. That's why it was expensive. It actually could produce the better sound but Gigabyte executives deprecated the audio chip a few months before I bought the motherboard. They started a new campaign called SoundBlaster Connect 2 and were selling sound cards.

Comment: New drivers for the motherboard intentionally prevented the audio chips from producing quality sound.  I called their tech support and they even admitted this to me. They also said they didn't have a single copy of the old driver. They said they lost it. Not a single copy? I searched everywhere in forums for about 3 months. I found 2-year-old posts which people state they were using the old driver and the sound was incredible but when I messaged them, they were all afk. The modern driver only plays dull sound, it doesn’t allow the SoundBlaster Connect software to produce quality sound.

Comment: After wasting so much time, I decided to sue them.  Well, luckily, in most states, what they did leads to triple damages for consumer fraud. There also is a federal law that states a company will get penalized for each incorrect statement they make about their warranty that is written, verbally stated, etc. I actually sued for $3k but the judge only gave me the $1k. That’s how it usually works though. If you have a similar problem, let me know and I’ll tell ya' how to sue. It takes a lot of time though like actually going to court and just waiting there and wasting a day. Just to warn ya'.

Comment: Anyway, I now have the money to replace my motherboard. I would still like a motherboard around the $200 that I paid for my old one but I could pay more if there is something really great and worth it for a little more. I love this motherboard because it has a lot of great fast ports in which I use all of them. I never could afford a motherboard like this before. Only problem is that the audio chip which was supposed to be fantastic and supposed to sound like just a sound card, didn't work from the beginning.

Comment: I would love to get a motherboard that has an integrated audio chip that sounds great so I don't need to buy a sound card. But, it's not really necessary. Sound cards don't cost that much anyway.
With the extra money I won though, I recently purchased a Pioneer 212UBK. This is something I'm excited about. It’s the only Blu-ray player that can actually play 4k movies and burn 100 gig M-Discs. It’s $150 which I think is a steal since other players all sell for about $100. For example, an LG player is cheaper at $110 and could do the same but it can only burn DVD M-Discs that hold 4.7 gigs.

Comment: One really bad thing about this Blu-ray player though is that it comes with some high motherboard and monitor requirements. These requirements, I highlighted in italics below. I actually haven't used my new Pioneer player because my motherboard doesn't meet the requirements. Below is the requirements that I wish or need for a new motherboard.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Sorry, it wasn't Romen but ArtofCode who is the moderator.

Comment: I don't know if you read my response above to your answer.  So, is AC1220 the best integrated audio chip on the market?  The problem was not the chip but the driver.  The manufacturer deliberately deprecated it so it wouldn't work with SoundBlaster 720°.  I know it's messed up.  I read this in a forum and confirmed by a Gigabyte tech that as SoundBlaster 720° wasn't taking off as they expected, they immediately pivoted to a SoundBlaster Connect 2 campaign.

Comment: From @QuietInMontana via the edit queue: "Question for You: I can't seem to direct a comment towards you so I have to contact you this way. I'm sorry. I'll edit this question out again. Does it mean that the 1220 is the best audio chip right now?

So, for my motherboard, it was supposed to play beautiful music and sound because of the software Sound BlasterX 720°. Is it possible that software can have that much impact on the audio chip? Why can't any other companies simply apply that similar software on all the other AC1220 chips on the market so it produces great sound?" (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) "Is there other software that I can use to produce the same results?"

Comment: Hey JMY, was there something that I was supposed to edit?